# How do I make a .net assembly filesize as small as possible?

Tags: .net, file, assemblies, size

I have a .net assembly that contains data access code (a bunch of Typed Datasets and helper classes) that is quite large on disk (~2.5MB).  What can I do to work out why it's so big and make it smaller?

Comment: if you are building in debug "mode" the assembly will contain debugging info, and thus, make it larger. building in release will make it smaller (at least in theory)

Comment: Any resources? Or any stored as resources?

Comment: You can possibly compress resources or DLL's, at the cost of slower application startup. [See this article](http://www.ddj.com/windows/184406005) or use the [free open source .NETZ tool here](http://madebits.com/netz/index.php).

Comment: It's not large, but it's 25% of my installer, and it's downloaded a lot so if I can optimise it a bit I can save the support guys a lot of waiting around for downloads.

Comment: Also, there are other assemblies that are of similar size, so it's general request for help, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the amount of information in the assembly.  If the typed datasets are not always used, moving the various ones into separate assemblies referenced by one central assembly can be an effective approach.  Then the runtime will only load the assemblies as needed.

Otherwise, there is little you can do without actually reducing the amount of code in the assembly itself.  An obfuscator can help reduce the size somewhat, since it will shrink the names, but this will likely be a minor improvement.

Answer (score 1):

MS ILMerge *might* make smaller assemblies (not too sure how it merges duplicate declarations etc)? worth a look i guess